# Could you disrupt the gravity of a black hole using quadrillions of supernova explosions?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, black-holes, astrophysics, supernova

For context, I’m planning a novel with as much ridiculous magic as ridiculous science so, yes I know, it’s impossible but that's the fun of mixing science and magic in worldbuilding.

So the situation is this:

- We have a 1 Trillion Solar Mass Supermassive Black Hole that must be destroyed
- The plan is to create two neutron balls of equal mass (small enough that their densities don't turn them into black holes themselves) and smash them into each other past the event horizon of the black hole (doing some magic stuff to avoid spaghettification and such (idk maybe teleport them via magic)), however, one of these neutron balls is made of antimatter.

according to: https://youtu.be/3ZWqQciAQlU?t=129

1 kg of regular matter hitting 1 kg of antimatter produces an explosive force of 1.89 x 10^17 joules of energy.
I did some cross-multiplication as to how much force would be generated from smashing 2x10^42 kg (the masses of the two previously mentioned neutron balls) and found that they'd produce a force of  3.78x10^59.

## To put that into perspective, that's 3.78 Quadrillion supernova explosions at once.

(Supernova explosion are 10^44 joules)

So back to the question. When I asked: Could you destroy a black hole from the inside using quadrillions of supernova explosions? I asked it because:

- I used this calculator https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/schwarzschild-radius to find the gravitational field of a black hole that size would be 15.212 m/s^2
- I used this website http://file.scirp.org/Html/11-7501495_40053.htm comparing event horizon radii to gravitational force which
  `"the gravitational force acting between the black holes and light particle decreases slowly with increasing the radius of the event horizon."`
  (and by slowly they mean exponentially, looking at the graph)
- According to https://www.universetoday.com/119733/how-quickly-does-a-supernova-happen/ supernovas explode at 23% the speed of light, which is a velocity of 70,000km/s^2

Noting that 70,000 is greater than 15.212, would that make it possible to disrupt the gravitational field of the black hole with 3.78 Quadrillon times the energy of a regular supernova?

Comment: If a question has been put on hold we better appreciate the user editing it instead of posting it again with slight variations. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand our community.

Comment: You cannot destroy a black hole with an explosion no matter how ridiculous its magnitude. No matter how much energy you impart to the particles that make it up, they'll be going at some speed less than the speed of light, which is insufficient to escape the black hole. Adding mass and energy to it will merely make it bigger.

Comment: A Blackhole do not have any gravitational binding energy so you can't tear it asunder

Comment: No. The mass-energy produced would only add to the black hole's gravitational field. Therefore, no disruption. You need better super-science to disrupt black holes. Try antigravity instead, it may be pseudoscience but conceptually it does a better job of disrupting gravity.

Comment: @a4android - For something less pseudoscientific than antigravity, physicists do sometimes speculate about "exotic matter" with [negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass), it wouldn't obviously violate any known laws of physics, though there's no evidence it exists. Dropping negative mass into a positive-mass black hole would in theory cause the black hole to lose mass and therefore shrink, see my comment [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/153421/59406).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Negative mass is a fine speculative concept. I was on the verge of suggesting it, but was in a mood for going science-fictional so I'm glad you mentioned it. There have been speculations about a form of antigravity, by physicists, driving the Big bang or something similar. I was playing with antigravity as either pseuodsience or speculative physics. However, your suggestion about negative mass is much better than antigravity in any form.